# How can I calculate the average outcome / expected value from a list of probabilities?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a question regarding calculating the expected outcome from the list or probabilities.

Suppose each can play a max of 6 games. If you win the game you move to the next round. Below I have a sample of a team the probability of reaching the certain round, how can I calculate to get the average expected number of games won?

```
Number of Games    1      2      3        4       5       6
% Chance to win  0.97   0.92    0.83    0.679   0.545   0.384
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: This is just a matter of applying the definition.  What goes wrong when you try to do that?

Comment: this would be 1*(.97) + 2(*.92).... etc which would give a value of 13.045. I am looking to get the expected number of games won which would have to be less than 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have the cumulative probabilities, and need the individual probabilities to calculate the expectation (using the standard method, at least).

If the probability of winning game 1 is $0.97$, that means this is the probability to win *at least* 1 game. The probability of winning exactly 1 game is the probability of winning at least 1, but not at least 2, i.e. $P(W=1)=0.97-0.92=0.05$. You can calculate the other probabilities similarly and use these to work out the expected number of games won in the usual manner.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above mentions you *could* manually calculate each of the probabilities for the total number of wins.

However you can also be lazy. The "tails sum" formula states that if a random variable, $X$, is Natural valued, that is the non-negative integers, then the expected value of $X$ is $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}[X \geq n]$

So in your case you could have just done $0.97+0.92+0.83+0.679+0.545+0.384 = 4.328 $